# How to place 3 columns properly in foundation flex grid

Tags: css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 6 on one of my clients website. I am using flex grid. However I am unable to understand why it is causing layout to have a space after 3 columns. The page having problem is http://hakara.in/archive/ 

I want 3 tiles to fit in the row. But there is white space at the end. How to fix that.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you show a bit code / sourcecode. On the link there is just the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `expanded` class from `#inner-content` to make it contain to the grid. If you want it to span the width of the screen, add `width: 100%`

Comment: removing the `expanded` class from `#inner-content` worked.